# How and where are lightsabers manufactured?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber

In The Force Awakens, we see only two lightsabers.

One is over 30 years old and belonged to Luke Skywalker.

The other was of unknown age and belonged to Kylo Ren.

Lightsabers are precision engineered products. There are very few lightsabers. We observe psychic phenomena when certain people touch a light saber. It's also not 100% clear that the psychic phenomena are due to the people who use the light saber, or due in some part to the lightsaber itself.

**So how are light sabers manufactured? Who manufactures lightsabers? What are lightsabers made of?**  I am hoping for an in-universe explanation.

[image: Kylo Ren with lightsaber]

Comment: I am 100% that this has already been asked and answered at least 2-3 times in the last year alone.

Comment: Just a few possible answers here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113969/why-do-lightsabers-attract-force-sensitives/113970#113970, here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113969/why-do-lightsabers-attract-force-sensitives/113971#113971, and here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/where-did-luke-skywalker-learn-to-build-his-own-lightsaber/114371#114371

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26824/who-makes-or-manufactures-lightsabers

Answer (score 3):

**1, Who makes them**

A part of the Jedi training is to construct his or her own lightsaber, which they can pretty much do wherever. Luke created his second lightsaber by himself, for instance.

As for the Sith, they create their own lightsabers as well. To be fair, in the EU it is not unheard of for Sith Masters to reward their apprentices with lightsabers they have not created themselves, for example

> Darth Bane's curve-hilted lightsaber was given to him by his by one of his instructors at the Sith Academy he was attending.

But of course, those lightsabers are also created one way or the other, and in that case

> It was created by the instructor's master.

So, to sum that up:
**The Jedi and Sith create their own lightsabers**, there is no 'lighsaber manufactor'

To address the point that they are rare in the original movies and episode VII. **It is not really that strange that there aren't many lightsabers around when there aren't many Jedi or Sith around.** In the prequels there is no shortage of lightsabers.

**2, How do they work**

The lightsaber blade is a plasma beam, and it is powered by a crystal. The crystal is also what determains the color of the blade. As Hypnosifl pointed out, the crystal is a kyber crystal. They could be found in the ice caves of Ilum, and a few other places. Apparently the kyber crystals are attuned to the Force and lacked color before being chosen by a Jedi. Once chosen, most crystals turned blue or green.

There are also synthetic crystals. These are artificially created crystals that are often much more powerful than the naturally formed ones. The Synth-crystals have a fixed color, most often red, and are used regularly buy the Sith. However, Luke's second lightsaber is powered by a green Synth-crystal.

**3, Psychic phenomena**

Unless you mean The Force, I don't know what you mean by that. The Force is what allow some individuals to get extraordinary powers, and my age has nothing to do with it! Oh, I mean the lightsabers has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The interior crystal you mention is a [kyber crystal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal), found mainly in the ice caves of [Ilum](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ilum). Apparently the crystals themselves were "Force attuned" in some way, the Jedis had to use the Force to find a crystal right for them, and once they picked it the crystal changed color to reflect the Jedi who chose it. Feel free to add this to your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Added the kyber crystal information to my answer. Also mentioned the artificially created Synth-crystals.